# Guardar info do cliente para próximos checkouts, mas sem ter de armazenar número de cartão? (Usando API)

Tags: php, javascript, pagamento-online, e-commerce, checkout

e desculpas antecipadas caso a pergunta não tenha sido muito clara, mas tentarei esclarecer o melhor possível:

Estou desenvolvendo um e-commerce relativamente simples com HTML, CSS, JS, Bootstrap, PHP, Apache, e MySQL.

Planejo usar uma API de pagamento tal como PagSeguro (preferível) ou MercadoPago. Quanto mais simples de implementar, melhor. Aceito novas sugestões.

O problema é: Quero que os clientes possam fazer checkout sem registro, ou criar uma conta para agilizar o processo da próxima vez, mas não quero armazenar informações sensíveis como dados bancários ou números de cartão no meu banco de dados, como creio que teria de fazer caso utilizasse o checkout transparente de ambas as APIs mencionadas (por favor me corrijam se eu não souber de alguma outra opção ou tenha entendido errado).

Eu poderia utilizar o lightbox ou o checkout por redirecionamento/iframe (que é o que eu prefiro e queria utilizar pela segurança), mas o problema é que assim então o usuário mesmo registrado teria de inserir novamente todas as informações e o registro seria uma função praticamente inútil.

Eu sei que pode soar como algo indeciso, mas preciso saber como oferecer praticidade sem ter de armazenar informações sensíveis em minha própria base.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Já que você não quer guardar informações confidenciais de seus clientes em seu servidor SQL, você pode usar Cookies para isso.

**Caso não saiba o que são Cookies:** [Resumidamente] Cookies são dados guardados ao acessar um site, nem todos sites utilizam cookies e nem todos cookies tem de ser "importantes" digamos assim. No seu caso é!

Você pode utilizar PHP para isso, basta saber: o que guardar, até quando guardar e identifica-lo. Observe:

```
<?php
$valor = array(
    "nome" => "Maicon",
    "sobrenome" => "Ferreira",
    "cidade" => "Cuiabá"
    );

setcookie("MeuCookie", $valor, time()+3600); // O time é em timestamp!

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Então, eu sei o que são cookies mas eles não me servem tanto pela falta de segurança (motivo tbm pelo qual não quero manter dados sigilosos no DB), quanto pelo fato de eu precisar manter um cadastro de cliente, e cookies podem ser limpos e vão ficar fixos à maquina. Eu não quero identificar o computador que compra, mas sim a conta de usuário. E usar informações do cadastro na próxima compra, exceto por dados bancários. Eu gostaria de poder fornecer só a identificação do usuário pra API, e deixar q ela cuidasse só dos dados de pagamento, mas eu não sei se é possível.

Comment: Não, algo desse tipo não é possível! Ou você guarda as informações no lado do cliente ou no lado do servidor. Todos métodos são inseguros, porém só há esses meios de guardarem informações para identificação de uma pessoa/maquina. Cookies podem ser inseguros, mas vai ser responsabilidade do usuário, e não sua! Já no BD, é sua e dele. OBS: Como deve saber, o Chrome pode guardar algumas informações de formulários para serem inseridos uma próxima vez.. Para agilizar o processo, você também pode usar redirect com PHP para checkout!